# Gorm invalid field found for struct

Tags: go, go-gorm

My database structure goal

```
one user can join many communities
and
one user can own a community
```

This is the structure that I came up with, is this correct?

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Communities []Community `gorm:"many2many:user_communities" json:"communities"`
    FirstName string `json:"firstName"`
    LastName string `json:"lastName"`
}

type Community struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `json:"name"`
    UserID uint `json:"userID"`
    Users []User `gorm:"many2many:user_communities" json:"users"`
}
```

This is my database setup

```
func ConnectMysql() {
    // Connect to Mysql database based on the environment variable
    dsn := os.Getenv("MYSQL_DSN")

    database, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to connect to the database")
    }

    database.AutoMigrate(&models.User{})
    database.AutoMigrate(&models.Community{})

    DB = database
}
```

and how do I query to check whether a user belongs to a community?

So far I came up with this but it's not working, probably my schema above is wrong

```
func CreateQuestion() {
    var community Community
    var foundUser User

    communityID = 1
    userID = 1

    // Find the community
    if err := database.Mysql.Where("id = ?", communityID).First(&community).Error; err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": "Community does not exist"})
        return
    }
    
    // Im not sure whether this query is to check whether the user belongs to the community with id 1 or not.
    if err := database.Mysql.Preload("Community").Where("id = ?", userID).Find(&foundUser).Error; err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": "user is not in the community"})
        return
    }
}
```

The error that I got

> [error] invalid field found for struct
> github.com/testing-be/Community's field Users: define a valid foreign
> key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you got this error is that gorm cannot find the foreign key for the defined relationship.

Add the ID field to both `User` and `Community` structs (or use `gorm.Model` instead of the ID). Also, add `many2many` for the `Communities` field as well.

```
type User struct {
    ID uint `json:"id"`
    Communities []Community `gorm:"many2many:user_communities" json:"communities"`
    FirstName string `json:"firstName"`
    LastName string `json:"lastName"`
}

type Community struct {
    ID uint `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    UserID uint `json:"userID"`
    Users []User `gorm:"many2many:user_communities" json:"users"`
}
```

By default, gorm will try to resolve the relationship like this:

```
// Join Table: user_communities
//   foreign key: user_id, reference: users.id
//   foreign key: community_id, reference: communities.id
```

If your foreign keys in the `user_communities` table are named differently, [here](https://gorm.io/docs/many_to_many.html#Override-Foreign-Key) is how you could handle that.

Regarding the `Preload` function, it takes field names, not field types, so the code should be something like this:

```
var foundUser User
    if err := database.Mysql.Preload("Communities").Where("id = ?", userID).First(&foundUser).Error; err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": "user is not in the community"})
        return
    }
```

This code loads all the communities that have a relationship with the found user.

**EDIT:**

The following examples should help you to determine if a specific user belongs to a specific community:

```
//Raw query
userID := 1
communityID := 1
var found sql.NullBool
if err := database.Mysql.Raw("SELECT 1 FROM users u JOIN user_communities uc ON u.id = uc.user_id WHERE u.id = ? AND uc.community_id = ?", userID, communityID).Scan(&found).Error; err != nil {
      c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": "error happened"})
            return
    }
if found.Valid && found.Bool {
  //user is part of the specified community
}

//With gorm functions
userID := 1
communityID := 1
var found sql.NullBool
if err := database.Mysql.Table("users u").Joins("JOIN user_communities uc ON u.id = uc.user_id").Where("u.id = ? AND uc.community_id = ?", userID, communityID).Select("1").Scan(&found).Error; err != nil {
      c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": "error happened"})
            return
    }
if found.Valid && found.Bool {
  //user is part of the specified community
}
```

Next, the examples on how to load a specified user with a specified community:

```
//Finds just the specified user and loads just a specified community
userID := 1
communityID := 1
var user User
err := database.Mysql.Preload("Communities", "id = ?", communityID).Joins("JOIN user_communities uc ON u.id = uc.user_id").Where("uc.community_id = ?", communityID).First(&user, userID).Error
// err could be gorm.ErrorNotFound, which means that a record is not found, so this needs to be checked before err != nil check

//Finds just the specified user, loads all user's communities, but makes sure that a user belongs to a specific community
userID := 1
communityID := 1
var user User
err := database.Mysql.Preload("Communities").Joins("JOIN user_communities uc ON u.id = uc.user_id").Where("uc.community_id = ?", communityID).First(&user, userID).Error
// err could be gorm.ErrorNotFound, which means that a record is not found, so this needs to be checked before err != nil check
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I've updated the question. I think the query is wrong to check whether user belongs to a specific community right?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do here. Do you just want to check if a user belongs to a specific community, or do you want to load a specific user but make sure that he belongs to a specific community?

Comment: Is it possible if you can show me both ways. Thanks man really appreciate the help

Comment: no problem, I've updated my answer with more examples :)

Comment: Thanks man really appreciate your help! i owe you big time :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might have missed `gorm.Model` in your structs?

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Communities []Community `json:"communities"`
    FirstName string `json:"firstName"`
    LastName string `json:"lastName"`
}

type Community struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `json:"name"`
    UserID uint `json:"userID"`
    Users []User `gorm:"many2many:user_communities" json:"users"`
}
```

https://gorm.io/docs/many_to_many.html

Comment: Okay i've added that, but the query is correct to check whether the user belongs to a community?

Comment: the community_id is 1 for example